# can't change Activity in android

Tags: java, android

I'm want to change Activity by choose from Menu in my activity but when i click to Menu the app is crashed and print this log:

I can't understand what this log say.I test my code There is nothing wrong in them.

```
 08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263): Process: com.example.aac_gps_gprs_v1, PID: 1263
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aac_gps_gprs_v1/com.example.aac_gps_gprs_v1.Frm_Server}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at com.example.aac_gps_gprs_v1.Frm_Server.onCreate(Frm_Server.java:48)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     ... 11 more
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     ... 23 more
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:575)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:410)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3545)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3475)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:464)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:236)
08-16 08:10:14.726: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     ... 26 more
```

Edit:

the Main layout that we are in it:

MainActivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/world_background_2"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:alpha="0.65"
    android:src="@drawable/as_logo" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:src="@drawable/title" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Btn_Taeed"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/window_2" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Txt_password"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Txt_Nkarbary"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Txt_Nkarbary"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Btn_Taeed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Txt_password"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Txt_password"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow_button"
    android:text="ورود" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Txt_password"
    android:src="@drawable/security_lock" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Txt_Nkarbary"
    android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Txt_Nkarbary"
    android:src="@drawable/user" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Txt_Nkarbary"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text|number"
    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_open_menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-14dp"
    android:background="@drawable/corner_menu"
    android:height="55dp"
    android:width="33dp"
    android:text="!!!"
    android:rotation="90"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

the layout that have to be start:

frm_server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_logon" >

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="سرور1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="سرور2" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="سرور 3" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="سرور4" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="سرور5" />
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_jostojo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:text="جستجوی خودکار سرور" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_Taeed_M1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:text="تایید" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bazgasht"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_Taeed_M1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_Taeed_M1"
    android:text="بازگشت" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_warning"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_warning"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
    android:text="در حال بررسی سرورها"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#fc0000"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It says there is something wrong in your layout xml, please post your layout xml

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. You're trying to allocate a `Bitmap` that is too large.

Comment: Yes I found it.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says there is something wrong in your layout xml file, so the error is thrown while inflating your layout. Please check if everything is correct in your layout and also see if there are any background images that have high resolution and reduce the resolution of the image.

Comment: I doubt this can be answer. It should be comment

Comment: Thanks.I use image with high resolution.